# Programmatically determine which content script to run

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm attempting to build a browser extension that changes the CSS of a website (among other things).

In the manifest.json file, one is able to specify a "matches" key to limit which sites the extension has permission to modify via the content script. Right now, I'm trying to present multiple different theme options, and each has its own CSS file.

Let's say I have three themes: theme1.css, theme2.css, and theme3.css

This is my save function, simply for reference.

```js
function save(theme) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"theme": theme}, function() {
        console.log('Set the theme to ' + theme)
        main()
    })
}
```

Currently, I have this in my manifest.json:

```js
"content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["style.css"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"]
}]
```

How can I check the stored theme to determine which one has been selected by the user, and then apply the corresponding CSS file if the URL is, let's say, https://example.com/?

Edit: I've since tried Declarative Content, this is what I've gotten. The Javascript is being injected but the CSS does not appear to be working.

```js
var theme1 = {
    conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'example.com', schemes: ['https'] }
        })
    ],
    actions: [ 
        new chrome.declarativeContent.RequestContentScript({
            js: [
                "content.js"
            ],
            css: [
                "css/theme1.css"
            ]
        })
    ]
};
```

```js
if (theme === "theme1") {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([theme1])
        console.log("Set theme to theme1")
    })
}
```

Comment: You can use chrome.declarativeContent API with RequestContentScript action (the documentation says it's experimental but it's not).

Comment: @wOxxOm I've been playing around with this one for a bit since you suggested it. While this appears to inject my content.js file, it does not seem to do the trick with the CSS. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Assuming you've used `css`, not `js`, to register it, there may be a bug in Chrome, or your css may be ineffective due to lower *specificity*.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've updated the original post to include my attempt at the rules. Prior to this I was editing the CSS using document root variables and some javascript to change the theme. This method worked fine except for a significant delay before loading the theme.

Comment: I guess then the problem is inside theme1.css or content.js